# How to build IVR with usb modem using asterisk?

Tags: linux, telephony

I have a [USB 3g modem](http://cgi.ebay.in/Huawei-3G-USB-Modem-E173-7-2Mbps-HSDPA-5-76Mbps-HSUPA-/280717541890?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item415c11c202#ht_988wt_1141), which also supports voice calling, I want to implement [IVR ( Interactive Voice response)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_voice_response#Voice-Activated_Dialling) with it on linux, Can I do it with Asterisk? If yes, then please help me on how to do this ( references) ?

Is there example or howtos available to do this?

Can I develop IVR system in linux without Asterisk?

Note: I am very new to Asterisk and IVR.

Comment: I will not post this as an answear because I dont know if you can use your 3G modem with Asterisk, but as you said, you dont know much about Asterisk system, so I would recomend you using TrixBox to start your learning. It is a virtual machine that you download and comes with asterisk configured. This will give you the easyest way to implement a IVR, just dragging and droping IVR boxes on a web configuration site. You will find more information on https://www.trixbox.org (This is a free and open source software)

Comment: +1 for trixbox, but either way, setting up a PBX from scratch is not an easy thing to do if you have no experience with voice. Troubleshooting is even harder.

Comment: http://jeremy-mcnamara.com/asterisk/how-to-configure-asterisk/ - This will get you started with a basic Asterisk setup (it is a bit outdated, but should still work). Here is a sample of IVR menus in Asterisk: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+tips+ivr+menu And here are some details about setting up the IVR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495271/setup-an-ivr-with-asterisk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this, relatively close.

http://www.elastix.org/component/kunena/25-newbies-corner-/61679-using-asterisk-with-usb-huawei-gsm-modem.html

Answer (score 1):

This may be possible but I doubt it.

Asterisk only supports specialist cards and the majority of 56k voice modems don't work.

Most 3G USB sticks simply emulate a 56k modem, and, I highly doubt they would have emulated any advanced features to make sure asterisk works.

I have personally never seen a 3g stick supporting voice, I am not entirely sure how this is even possible, but, after searching for Huawei modem support in Asterisk, I just can't find anything.

Sorry!  I wish there was better news.

Comment: Thanks for answer, This modem comes with a windows software, with this software you can use PC 's mic and headphone to make a call, even sms functionalities are there in this. some newer sticks even support video calling.

Comment: William, Is there any other way ( I mean without Asterisk) to achive IVR creation on linux?

Comment: @Sunny Shah - Not that I know of. Sorry :( All VOIP software is very picky over lines you can use. If the software is just an interface, then, you may be able to use it... if it is the entire driver in one, you won't be able to.... I really doubt it. Can you try to take a few screenshots and I will see if I can understand what is going on and try to help you further.